# How to correctly parse Reddit API in Android

Tags: java, android, json, reddit

So I've been trying to parse Reddits r/hot/.json API to get a list view of topic information but I cant seem to get my JSON right. I've looked everywhere and I cant seem to find a good example on how to do this for reddit. Here is what I have so far..

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray hotTopics = data.getJSONArray("children");

        for(int i=0; i<hotTopics.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject topic = hotTopics.getJSONObject(i);

            String author = topic.getString("author");
            String imageUrl = topic.getString("thumbnail");
            String postTime = topic.getString("created_utc");
            String rScore = topic.getString("score");
            String title = topic.getString("title");

            topicdata.add(new ListData(title, author, imageUrl, postTime, rScore));
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,topicdata.toString());
        }
```

-------Edit
Okay to give more details I did a HttpGet Request on "http://www.reddit.com/r/hot/.json?sort=new&count=25"
When I run my code as it stands I'm getting the following JSONException

`07-06 22:23:11.628    2580-2580/com.google.android.gms.redditviewr.app W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for author
07-06 22:23:11.632    2580-2580/com.google.android.gms.redditviewr.app W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
07-06 22:23:11.632    2580-2580/com.google.android.gms.redditviewr.app W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:514)
07-06 22:23:11.636    2580-2580/com.google.android.gms.redditviewr.app W/System.err﹕ at Tasks.RedditApiTask.onPostExecute(RedditApiTask.java:78)
07-06 22:23:11.636    2580-2580/com.google.android.gms.redditviewr.app W/System.err﹕ at Tasks.RedditApiTask.onPostExecute(RedditApiTask.java:22)
07`

Which is pointing to the first item in my JSON parsing logic. But it makes no sense because there is indeed all of those items in the children array.

Comment: What is your question? More importantly, what happens when you run your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: well showing the JSON you are attempting to parse would surely help!

Comment: Okay I added some more details to the post. Im getting a JSONException

Comment: check out your output JSON String and see if it has this tag "author"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to go one more level deeper since the structure is

```
result
-- data
---- children
------ data
-------- author
-------- thumbnail
-------- created_utc
-------- score
-------- title
```

Try something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < hotTopics.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject topic = hotTopics.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");

    String author = topic.getString("author");
    String imageUrl = topic.getString("thumbnail");
    String postTime = topic.getString("created_utc");
    String rScore = topic.getString("score");
    String title = topic.getString("title");

    topicdata.add(new ListData(title, author, imageUrl, postTime, rScore));
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, topicdata.toString());
}
```

Comment: Yup that did for me. Gee, thanks Sreekesh Okky. You're awesome

Comment: Where the heck does one find the structure? I'm not sure if it's just me being a newb, but Reddit's api documentation has been a bit hard to follow & understand

Comment: Thank you so much for this! My first reaction was to find a library to simply get topic URLs. I got jReddit and spent hours trying to get it (and its crazy amount of dependencies) to work and was never successful. Thankfully I found this!

Answer (score 4):

You can make your life easier if you use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) + [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Or you can add [rest2mobile](http://is.gd/X8tzc9) plug-in/library to your Android Studio that will do implement the same functionality at once.See the reddit based with rest2mobile example [here](http://is.gd/Hcpp6E).